# How do I add a querystring when using the MVC PagedList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagedlist

How would I go about adding a query string to the Razor Helper PagedListPager below ?

```
@Html.PagedListPager( (IPagedList)Model.PartsList, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }) )
```

Comment: I don't understand why someone would mark this question down.  Can someone give me some insight ?  I don't want to contribute useless info to stackoverflow.  Did I do so here ?

Comment: Blind downvoting is annoying. I can understand it if someone else already stated the reason. But anyway, I think the issue is that (1) the question seems a bit short and not fleshed out (2) we're not sure what you've tried, if anything. Not trying to complain, just trying to give you objective reasons :) Don't worry, we all had to learn how to ask proper SO questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't add query parameters in `PagedListPager`, you do them in `Url.Action`.

Below is an updated version of your code, I've added a query parameter `tag`.

```
Url.Action("Index", new { page, tag = 'asp' })
```

The URL would generate the following query string

```
?page=1&tag=asp
```

Here is the same `Url.Action` within `PagedListPager`:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
    (IPagedList)Model.PartsList, 
    page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, tag = 'asp' }))
```

Comment: For completeness, it would render: `?page=1&tag=asp`. `&`, not `%`. But for the rest, you're spot on :) Sorry if I'm being pedantic :)

Comment: what if we have alot more parameters? and dynamic parameters we dont know if they exists in url?

Answer (score 1):

You simply add more query parameters

```
Url.Action("Index", new { page, tag = "asp", tag1 = "value1", tag2 = "value2" })
```

The URL would generate the following query string

```
?page=1&tag=asp&tag1=value1&tag2=value2
```

If a value is null the query string is not included in generated URL

```
Url.Action("Index", new { page, tag = "asp", tag1 = "value1", tag2 = "" })

?page=1&tag=asp&tag1=value1
```

Many thanks to Yorro!