# Ajax PagedList Reload returns first page everytime

Tags: c#, pagedlist

I implement PagedList to support pagination on my view. And I use EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing to make it ajaxicaly. Everything works fine except when I reload the page in the browser. Since there isn't any information in the url about the page number, after page reload it loads first page everytime.
I wander is there a way to reload the page but stay on the page before reload?

Here is my pagination code

```
Page @(Model.PagedList.PageCount < Model.PagedList.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PagedList.PageNumber) of @Model.PagedList.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(
    Model.PagedList,
    page => Url.Action("List", new { page, currentFilter = Model.SearchString }),
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "search"})
    )
```

My Url looks like

```
http://localhost:1334/AdminDashboard/List?searchString=d&DocSort=DocIDesc
```

I think

```
http://localhost:1334/AdminDashboard/List?searchString=d&DocSort=DocIDesc&page=5
```

would solve the problem,but because of `EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing` parameter the page number isn't added to the url automatically when I change the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a querystring when using the MVC PagedList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463685/how-do-i-add-a-querystring-when-using-the-mvc-pagedlist)

Comment: The difference between my question and the question you referenced is that  the problem is in usage of `EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing`. If I don't use tihs parameter everything works fine. The query string works fne.